# Dock disappeared after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, only visible in Activities overview

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, 19.10

Had my dock on bottom (+autohide) in Ubuntu 19.04. After upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10 it disappeared and can be found now only in *Activities* overview.

I can start apps from there and it has all apps that I have added there but can't get it to be in the original place and on desktop, not in Activities.

Tried **Settings** -> *Dock* and none of the 3 settings (Auto hide, Icon size, Position) have any effect.

Output 
$apt policy gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock

gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:

Installed: 67ubuntu19.10.1

Candidate: 67ubuntu19.10.1

Version table:

*** 67ubuntu19.10.1 500

500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages

500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages

100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Restarting desktop with "r" does not correct the proble, Dock still in Activities.

Comment: According to a comment by user paravane on gnome extensions site, "To everyone getting errors after upgrading to 19.10 ALT+F2 type "r" then press enter. (without the quotes) This will restart your shell and your dock will appear at the bottom."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled `dash to dock` extension and execute this

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/
```

then reboot.

Comment: just a reminder,  reboot !

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and this worked for me
I reinstalled 'ubuntu-dock' by using this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

check for docks in settings after the installation

If it's already installed, but problem persists try to reconfigure it with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

Comment: This is not `dash-to-dock`, this is `ubuntu-dock`.

Comment: I had the same problem, even Dock section in settings wasn't working until I installed this package

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me I reinstalled 'dash to dock' by using this command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

The workaround is to reboot the Gnome shell by following the protocols presented below.
1.Press ALT + F2.
2.In the pop-up terminal, type r and press Enter.

The Gnome shell will restart without breaking the existing processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try activating *Ubuntu dock* under the *Extensions* tab of the [GNOME tweak tools](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
sudo mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

- Then Press **F2** and type `r`

### References

- https://vinnyfs89.gitbook.io/knowledge/technology/operational-systems/linux/desktop-environment/gnome/known-issues#gnome-shell-dock-disappear

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this, immediately after upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04 Jammy, I had no Dock.  Also under Appearance in the Settings application there was only a section for Style, no section for Dock. After a couple of restarts and still no Dock, I ran

> `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`

(as mentioned above in a previous answer) and restarted.  The Dock is back and a Dock section now appears under Appearance in Settings.